# Lenovo Y500 Invisible Mouse Cursor

Tags: windows-8, mouse

Title pretty much says it all. I downloaded an automatic quality of life update for WIN8 last night and ever since then have been unable to see my mouse cursor. I can still highlight/click things (albeit with great difficulty) so I know the cursor is there -- the problem lies with the absence of the cursor sprite.

If anyone knows about this and has any potential suggestions as to how to remedy this issue that would be awesome.

Comment: Have you got any restore points? Where did you download the update from and how was it called?

Comment: Just as a workaround while you solve this issue, you can try enabling the *show cursor position* option with the Ctrl key.

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods to solve this. Here's a couple that I know.

- Windows 8 has an option to *hide the pointer*, go to the control panel and under `Mouse` → `Settings` look for the `Hide` setting and un-check it. Also, try using the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> keys (F1, F2, …) look for one that resembles a cursor or a trackpad (commonly <kbd>F5</kbd>), it is a shortcut to that setting on most computers.
- Reboot your machine. Don't shutdown and turn on again. *Reboot* it. Windows 8 doesn't shut down the system (because of fast-boot), it just pseudo-hibernates it.